# Decide whether sentence (3) is true if sentences (1) and (2) are both true.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

This is Problem 4.20 (g) of the textbook ["Reading, Writing, and Proving - A Closer Look at Mathematics", Chapter 4](https://books.google.com/books?id=4QKcaXrVZb0C&pg=PA33&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false), 2nd ed. Springer, 2003 by Ulrich Daepp and Pamela Gorkin.

> Decide whether sentence (3) is true if sentences (1) and (2) are both true. Give reasons for your answers.
>
> Let $M$ and $n$ be real numbers.
>   (1) If $n > M$, then $n^2 > M^2$.
>   (2) We know that $n < M$.
>   (3) So $n^2 \le M^2$.

I am confused by the following three different ideas:

1. (3) is false.
   Reason: Take $n = -2, M = -1$.
2. (3) is true.
   Reason: From (1), we can conclude that $n > 0$. Together with (2), we have $0 < n < M$. Therefore, we have $n^2 < M^2$, which implies $n^2 < M^2$.
3. We cannot decide whether (3) is true or not.
   Reason: (1) can be formulated as $n > M \to n^2 > M^2$, while (2) as simply n < M. From these two formulas, we cannot logically conclude either $n^2 \le M^2$ or $n^2 > M^2$.

Which is correct? What is your opinion?

Specifically, I am not sure whether we are allowed to make reasonings based on our knowledge about real numbers, as done in the second idea. What do you think of it?

Comment: The question asks whether (2) and (3) imply (1). If using (1) and (2) you can't decide whether (3) is true, then (2) and (3) don't imply (1).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you mean "the question asks whether (1) and (2) imply (3)"? I am not sure whether we can make reasonings based on our knowledge about real numbers, as done in the second idea. What do you think of it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, whether (1) and (2) imply (3). I would say you're not meant to use what you know about the reals, but it's hard to tell without context, without having the book in front of me.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have copied all the content of the problem itself. In that chapter (Chapter 4), the book is giving a (quite informal) introduction to logic. You can have a flavor of it in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=4QKcaXrVZb0C&pg=PA33&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Your idea 2. is faulty, because the only thing we can conclude (even with our knowledge of the real numbers) is that $M \geq 0$, not that $n>0$. So $n = -1, M = 0$ satisfies both (1) and (2), but not (3).

Comment: @Arthur Why not? If $n <= 0$, we cannot have $n^2 > M^2$ given $n > M$  in (1), then (1) is not true. (Actually, I am quite confused about what is known and what is not.)

Comment: @Arthur So, you agree with the first idea?

Comment: @hengxin I'm a bit confused by the problem, actually. If $M$ and $n$ are fixed before the three conditions are stipulated, then your idea 1. works, or at least it proves that (1) and (2) does not always imply (3). This is what the problem actually says, but it feels like a strange thing to ask about. If only $M$ is fixed, and $n$ can freely be picked to be any number that fulfills requirement (1) and (2) (which, if I were to read minds, I believe is closer to the problem that the author intended), then (1) and (2) still doesn't imply (3), as evidenced by my example.

Comment: I am sure there are other interpretations as well. In short, I have no idea what is actually asked, but I believe the answer is that (1) and (2) does not imply (3) regardless.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if there aren't any further conditions then the deduction rule $(1)$ is wrong. Hence if you assume that it is right you can derive any statement.

Anyway there is an easy way to actually do this:
Let $n,M \in \mathbb{R}$ and the deduction rule

$$(1) \quad n>M \Longrightarrow n^2 > M^2$$

true. Then let us switch the roles of $n$ and $M$ and we obtain

$$(1)' \quad M<n \Longrightarrow M^2 < n^2$$

Now subsitute $M$ with $n$ and the other way round.

$$(1)'' \quad n<M \Longrightarrow n^2 < M^2$$

Now we use $(2)$ combined with $(1)''$ and due [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) we obtain
$$n^2 < M^2$$
which clearly implies the weaker statement $n^2 \leq M^2$.

Comment: When you switched the roles of $M$ and $n$, why did you switch the $(<,>)$ sign as well? They are just variables, it's not that any of them was meant to be on one side of the $<$ sign,right?

Comment: I just made it extra slow. First step is just the inequality from an other point of view. Second step is the actual substitution. You are right you can skip this step and go immediately to $(1)''$